# How to make relations work properly using Laravel Eloquent Models that inherit from each other

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, routes

We have a table `invoices` which has a nullable field `number`.
Our business logic is as follows.

Whenever we need to charge a customer for a renewal of their services, we send them a Proforma Invoice.  Proforma invoices are recognised by the attribute `number` being empty.

Whenever we want to convert a proforma invoices (manually or automatically because the customer paid), all we basically have to do is determine a new number and update `invoice.number`.  This feature works great.

Now we want to have a route `GET /api/invoices/201900001`which - as you guess correctly - is supposed to fetch the invoice `WHERE number = 201900001`.

So we defined our invoice model as follows:

```
class Invoice extends Model {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'number';
    }
}
```

works brilliantly.  But I guess you know what else that we need.  We also need to be able to fetch the proforma invoices using a route `GET /api/proformas/1` where 1 is in fact the `id` and not the `number` of the record, as you know that we don't assign a number to proforma invoices, but only assign once we charge a proforma invoices and convert it into an invoice.

So our first question was whether there is a way to set what column a route parameter needs to bind to for an individual route, but that seems impossible, so we took another route.  If you see a solution that does allow me to support both binding to number and id depending on the route, then by all means, let me know :-)

Anyway, we continued our work, and we then thought that a `ProformaInvoice` is in fact a specific sub type of an `Invoice` object, so we went ahead and created a new model for this purpose:

```
Class ProformaInvoice extends Invoice {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        // override parent's behaviour back to the default
        return 'id';
    }
}
```

Wow - we believed this was to solve our issues, but it didn't.
Because guess what - we also have InvoiceElements, and they are linked to an invoice.

So we have this great relation on the invoice model:

```
Class Invoice extends Model {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'number';
    }

    public function invoice_elements() {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceElement::class);
    }
}
```

Since we now have our own ProformaInvoice model, we moved the logic of actually charging a proforma invoice to that class (it previously was on the `Invoice` model itself):

```
public function ProformInvoice extends Invoice {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'id';
    }

    public function convertToInvoice() {
        $minNumber = (date('Y') * 100000) + 1;
        DB::statement(
            "UPDATE invoices inv
             JOIN (
                 SELECT IF(IFNULL(MAX(number)+1,1) < " . $minNumber . ", " . $minNumber . ", MAX(number) + 1) AS newNumber
                 FROM invoices
             ) t
             SET inv.number = t.newNumber, invoice_date = NOW(), updated_at = NOW()
             WHERE id = " . $this->id;
        );
        return Invoice::find($this->id);
    }
}
```

We thought we were really smart, because our `CreateInvoiceController` now works like this, and makes perfect sense to us:

```
Class CreateInvoiceController extends Controller {
    public function create(CreateInvoiceRequest $request) {
        $invoice = null;
        DB::transaction(function() use($request, &invoice) {
            $proforma = ProformaInvoice::create([
                'due_date' => $request->get('due_date'),
                'subtotal' => $request->get('subtotal'),
                'vat' => $request->get('vat');
                'total' => $request->get('total');
            ]);

            $proforma->invoice_elements()->createMany($request->get('elements'));

            $invoice = $proforma->convertIntoInvoice();
        }, 1);

        return InvoiceResource::make($invoice);
    }
}
```

Okay, so executing this threw an exception, namely `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'proforma_invoice_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'invoice_elements'...`

This actually made sense to me, as the relationship is defined on the Invoice model, and inherited by the ProformaInvoice model.  When trying to create related models, it makes perfect sense that it did not use the correct column name `invoice_id`, as we didn't explicitely define the foreign key when defining the relationship, so I though we had a quick fix, namely explicitely define the foreign key on the relationship definition:

```
Class Invoice extends Model {
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'number';
    }

    public function invoice_elements() {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceElement::class, 'invoice_id');
    }
}
```

Much to my surprise, however, this does not solve the issue; I'm still getting the error that column `proforma_invoice_id` does not exist even though I explicitely set the foreign key definition to `invoice_id` on its definition...

Am I overlooking something, or is this a bug in the framework?

Would you advise another path that makes more sense to you?  To me, this makes perfect sense now, but there might be another solution...

I could also just not do model binding, and fetch the model myself in the controller, but I'd like to keep the code as clean as possible and make use of model binding whenever possible when setting up routes.

If you got here - THANKS for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you have taken a really complicated and roundabout way of doing things.
When you write something like

```
Route::get('invoices/{invoice}', 'InvoiceController@show');
```

Laravel knows {invoice} can be used with Route Model Binding to get an Invoice instance directly instead of passing only the id by putting `(Invoice $invoice)` as parameter in your controller method instead of just `($invoice)`.

What if you don't want to use the id to find a model? As you know, you can override the `$routeKeyName` attribute. But you still want to use the `$id` in a way.

What you should do in my opinion, is **add another binding in your RouteServiceProvider file**.

Example.

```php
# app/Invoice.php
class Invoice extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'number';
    }
    ...
}
```

```php
# app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php
use App\Invoice;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        // bind {proforma_invoice} param to Invoice model
        Route::model('proforma_invoice', Invoice::class, function ($param) {
            // Since you want the id, we use findOrFail so it throws a 404 instead of a null.
            // You can customize the logic.
            // more info on https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing
            return Invoice::findOrFail($param);
        });
    }
}
```

```php
# routes/api.php

// matches GET api/invoices/1234564
// tries to match invoice by its number attribute because of the routeKeyName override
Route::get('invoices/{invoice}', 'InvoiceController@showInvoice');
// matches GET api/proformas/1234564
// uses the definition in RouteServiceProvider to try and match an invoice
Route::get('proformas/{proforma_invoice}', 'InvoiceController@showProforma')
```

```php
class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    ...
    public function showProforma(Invoice $invoice) { ... }
    public function showInvoice(Invoice $invoice) { ... }
}
```

This way, it's only using the Invoice model and you won't have to juggle things around to make relationships work.

Without more info on the sql query that makes your relationship method fails, I can't be of much help there. I thought it might be because of the third parameter (local key), which is supposed to be the model's primary key but it makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm going to try this immediately - as I wrote in my initial question - if you have a solution to fix the different bindings in the routes themselves, this would be the ideal solution - I wasn't aware I could create a specific binding using the `Route::model()` method, so this looks like the most ideal solution indeed!

Will let you know the outcome!  THanks so much already

Comment: You're welcome. If all else fails remember you're not forced to use route model binding.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I wanted to try and make sure I can keep the model binding; makes the controllers nicer...

Comment: Hi - I jave reverted the code back; only need to test the proforma route still - once I’ve done that I’ll mark your answer ;-). It’ll probably work, I’m sure!  Thanks again for the fine answer!